# Extract and compare eventargs data

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

I have a problem comparing data I get from an eventargument, to be more specific, I have 2 classes that uses an interface, lets call it 'IInt'. I also have a list that is filled with objects of these two classes.

I currently use the OnDragDrop event to drag objects from this list, but I need a way to determine if it was an object of class1 or class2 that I draged. Is there a way to extract the data and compare it using the DragEventArgs drgevent?

So first of all, when I grab an object from the list.

```
foreach (IInt d in dlist)
    DoDragDrop(d.GetType(), DragDropEffects.Move);
```

And when I want to extract the data ie check what object was draged.

```
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
    {
        if (drgevent.GetType() == typeof(DragedObject))
            do stuff...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finally getting to the root of this, it appears that your answer is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx)

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(YourType))) {
    YourType item = (YourType)e.Data.GetData(typeof(YourType));
```

If I am understanding you correctly, then you are looking for [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can use [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

```
arg.GetType() == typeof(Class1)
```

or [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
arg is Class1
```

**UPDATE**

Without more code than provided, here is what it sounds like you need to do:

```
foreach (IInt d in dlist)
    DoDragDrop(d, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

`DoDragDrop` sounds like it will create the DragEventArgs from the object and effect, so you would want something like this:

```
protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
{
    if (drgevent.dObject.GetType() == typeof(DraggedObject))
        do stuff...
}
```

Notice that you are not testing the arg itself, instead you are testing what it contains.

Comment: Doesen't seem to work, on my DoDragDrop I send the type of the item from the list<IInt> like so: 
DoDragDrop(obj.GetType(), DragDropEffect.Move) (where obj is the ref variable inside a foreach loop that goes through the entire list)

Comment: You should probably upload an example snippet. If your DoDragDrop is expecting a type, then this is correct, but if it is expecting an object where you will test the type, then it is wrong.

Comment: True, edited op to make it more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Jacco This still isnt helpful. The full story is missing...It seems that maybe you want to pass `d` into `DoDragDrop` instead of its type. But, I dont know how it all gets down to the Arg level...

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, so maybe my attempts are completely off, idk.. But hopefully what I want to achieve is clear enough, send something from a list, and on a later point get the type of it. I'm not sure how else I can explain it, all I know is what I've tried doesen't work for now.

Comment: @Jacco I have updated my answer to guess what you are trying to say. Again, without more code, I am only guessing at the internals.

Comment: I see, what would dObject be? I can skip it and just say "drgevent.GetType()" but that just gives me DragEventArgs, wich is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25800/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-jacco)